# Reference request for texts that take conditional probability as more foundational than probability itself

Tags: probability, reference-request, conditional-probability

I want to know, are there any texts out there that take conditional probability as more primitive and define probability in terms of conditional probability? Perhaps they give some axioms for conditional probability. Anyway, I would be very interested in such texts.

Comment: Jaynes might be worth a look.